# Problem: Munin Graph

Tags: munin, graph

I've been trying to install Munin for 15 days, I looked for information, analized logs, I even deleted and reinstalled Munin using YUM. I'm hosted at Media Temple on a VPS with CentOS. The problem is still there and It's driving me nuts.

Graphics are shown as following:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/capturadepantalla201106u.png/

This is the configuration of my munin.conf file

```
dbdir   /var/lib/munin
htmldir /var/www/munin
logdir  /var/log/munin
rundir  /var/run/munin

[localhost]
    address **.**.***.*** #IP VPS
```

This is the configuration of my munin-node.conf file

```
log_level 4
log_file /var/log/munin/munin-node.log
port 4949
pid_file /var/run/munin/munin-node.pid
background 1
setseid 1

# Which port to bind to;
host *
user root
group root
setsid yes

# Regexps for files to ignore

ignore_file ~$
ignore_file \.bak$
ignore_file %$
ignore_file \.dpkg-(tmp|new|old|dist)$
ignore_file \.rpm(save|new)$

allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$
```

Thanks so much,  I appreciate all the answers

UPDATE munin-graph.log

```
Jun 22 16:30:02 - Starting munin-graph
Jun 22 16:30:02 - Processing domain: localhost
Jun 22 16:30:02 - Graphed service : open_inodes (0.14 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:02 - Graphed service : sendmail_mailtraffic (0.10 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:02 - Graphed service : apache_processes (0.12 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:02 - Graphed service : entropy (0.10 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:02 - Graphed service : sendmail_mailstats (0.14 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:02 - Graphed service : processes (0.14 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:03 - Graphed service : apache_accesses (0.27 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:03 - Graphed service : apache_volume (0.15 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:03 - Graphed service : df (0.21 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:03 - Graphed service : netstat (0.19 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:03 - Graphed service : interrupts (0.14 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:03 - Graphed service : swap (0.14 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:04 - Graphed service : load (0.11 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:04 - Graphed service : sendmail_mailqueue (0.13 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:04 - Graphed service : cpu (0.21 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:04 - Graphed service : df_inode (0.16 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:04 - Graphed service : open_files (0.16 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:04 - Graphed service : forks (0.13 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:05 - Graphed service : memory (0.26 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:05 - Graphed service : nfs_client (0.36 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:05 - Graphed service : vmstat (0.10 sec * 4)
Jun 22 16:30:05 - Processed node: localhost (3.45 sec)
Jun 22 16:30:05 - Processed domain: localhost (3.45 sec)
Jun 22 16:30:05 - Munin-graph finished (3.46 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this problem is b/c you're missing the font that munin is using to graph the rrd data.

Are there any errors in /var/log/munin/munin-graph.log?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't find errors on the logs of the munin-graph, although I will paste it on the question so you can see it.

Thanks again.

Comment: This looks very much like a font issue. +1

Comment: The graphs come from rrdtool which has a hard coded default font.  Here's a good tutorial on installing rrdtool on RHEL which should work for CentOS.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-rrdtool-on-rhel-linux/

Comment: Thanks to everyone, Munin finally worked 100%. The problem was in fact an RRDDTool library error, I upgraded and everything worked perfectly. Thanks again!